# Cisco DHCP discover with multiple routers - dhcp discover without reply

Tags: cisco, router, dhcp, ip

i have the following network:

[image: Topology]

The lower right router shall be my dhcp server (net 192.168.2.0/24 - ip 192.168.2.3)

It shall provide IPs for the upper left and lower left PCs and Printers.

The lower left net: 192.168.1.0/24 The upper left: 192.168.0.0/24

I configured the ip helper-address 192.168.2.3 on the lower left routers for vlan 2 interface witch is the one connected to the switches

If i wireshark the connection i cann see the DHCP discover message reaching the router in the lower right. The problem is: i don't get a reply from the dhcp server.

This is the config of it:

```
ip dhcp excluded-address 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.30

ip dhcp pool area1
network 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
! (192.168.1.2 is the vlan interface of the lower left router)
default-router 192.168.1.2
```

EDIT// Just found out that my DHCP Server 'prentends' sending out dhcp offers ... but they never reach the client or even the next router as you can see on this wireshark snap:

[image: DHCP]

And additionally if i enter 'show ip dhcp binding' the server did assign an ip (192.168.1.31) to the correct mac address .... but it just never reached the client

Another question: Is there a possibility to put the second interface of the dhcp server into the same subnet for redundancy reasons?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem:

i was able to ping the dhcp router via the lower left router but never tried vise versa. I assumed as the dhcp discover can reach the router there shouldn't be a problem.

Actually the 192.168.1.0 net was missing in the lower left eigrp tables, and the dhcp discover could only reach the server 'cos of the ip helper-address...

I should have tried it for the upper left ones earlier, because everything was fine there, it took me far to long to figure this out -.-